# Adding multiple IIF statements SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to add together multiple fields IF the underlying condition is true.

More specifically, I want to add together fields only if they meet or exceed a parameter set by the user.

I feel like this is the closest I've come. I would really appreciate any help! Thank you

```
=IIF(Fields!TestA.Value >= Parameters!TestA.Value,Fields!TestA.Value,0)
+IIF(Fields!TestB.Value >= Parameters!TestB.Value,Fields!TestB.Value,0)
+IIF(Fields!TestC.Value >= Parameters!TestC.Value,Fields!TestC.Value,0)
```

The idea is to first test to see if the field is greater than or equal to the parameter, if it is great, add that to the total otherwise just add 0 to the total and move on.

Comment: Your code seems ok. Do you have any problem?

Comment: From your description and code, that looks fine, what exactly is wrong?

Comment: It's not throwing any errors, it just seems to be adding everything together whether the parameter is met or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fields or parameters are text/string then you may need to convert them to and INT or decimal number with INT() or CDEC(). Otherwise the IIF may be doing the comparison as a string rather than a number comparison (ex. `"2" > "100"`).

Try converting your fields to an INT:

```
=IIF(INT(Fields!TestA.Value) >= INT(Parameters!TestA.Value), Fields!TestA.Value, 0)
+IIF(INT(Fields!TestB.Value) >= INT(Parameters!TestB.Value), Fields!TestB.Value, 0)
+IIF(INT(Fields!TestC.Value) >= INT(Parameters!TestC.Value), Fields!TestC.Value, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct,
You wish to set value for Field A, Field B and Field C

so for Field A you condition should be

```
=IIF(Fields!TestA.Value >= Parameters!TestA.Value,Fields!TestA.Value,0)
```

For Field B it should be

```
=IIF(Fields!TestB.Value >= Parameters!TestB.Value,Fields!TestB.Value,0)
```

similarly it goes for C.

Let me know If I am missing something or you want to set value with checking multiple conditions for a single field?